# jProfiler throws error due to unclosed meta tag that does not exist

Tags: java, html, profiling, jprofiler

I have a java application which need to be profiled by jProfiler. 
First time that I ran the jProfiler it showed an error on the following line.
But even after removing the line it is still showing the same error.
Even restarting jProfiler, Java and application did not work. It seems this line will be generated automatically.

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I also added the closing tag and when I check the source of the file it is like following but jProfiler error still says the meta tag has not been closed yet.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
```

**I follow these steps:**

Run Java Web Application then on JProfiler

New Session > Launch (Web Start) > Copy URL into "URL of the JNLP file" 'http:// localhost : 8080/User/Profile' > OK > 
Instrumentation > OK

**Error**

Unable to launch the application > Details >

Error : could not parse launch file. Error at line 125.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
Line 125>>> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

It is weird as this meta tag is not included in my code.

Comment: JProfiler does not parse HTML. Can you describe the error message more in detail?

Comment: @IngoKegel question is updated.

Comment: "URL of the JNLP file" is for webstart applications. This has nothing to do with web applications. Use Session->Integration wizards->New server integration instead.

Comment: My server is not included in the list that is GlassFish 4 but is not included in the list. I am using Netbeans 8.0 and JProfiler 8.0.5. I even integrated the JProfiler with Netbeans and ran debug before running JProfiler plugin but it shows an information dialog box which says For free-form projects, you need to execute the debug action once before profiling is possible... Another thing is that, I could get list of my application classes in JProfiler by New Session > Attach > Select from all local JVMs > selecting glassfish\domains\domain1 > OK and then running application on netbeans

Comment: but not sure whether it is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: You can always use the [Generic] integration wizard and add the VM parameter for profiling manually as explained by the wizard.